# Plot with python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

Hello i know that this way to plot in matlab works:

```
subplot(2,2,[1, 2])
plot(Tabsauv(:, 2:2:2*Ntracks), Tabsauv(:, 3:2:(2*Ntracks+1)),couleur,'LineWidth',2, 'MarkerSize', 2)
grid('on')
hold on
```

When Tabasauv is a table of values.

I'm a new beginner in python, I tried to plot this in this way with python but it still not working, any idea?

```
 80 Ntracks=5
 81 fig= plt.figure()
 82 ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
 83
 84 data_1=np.array([:,2:2:(2*Ntracks)])
 85 data_2=np.array([:,3:2:(2*Ntracks+1])
 86 points = data[:,2:4]
 87
 88 color = np.sqrt((points**2).sum(axis = 1))/np.sqrt(2.0)
 89 rgb = plt.get_cmap('jet')(color)
 90
 91 ax.scatter(data_1, data_2, color = rgb)
 92 plt.show()
```

I got this error caus' i don't know how to translate it in python:

```
    data_1=np.arange([:,2:2:(2*Ntracks)])
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you.

Comment: You would get an answer very quickly if you just (clearly) stated what you want `np.arange([:,2:2:(2*Ntracks)])` to be.  As it is, I added `numpy` and `matlab` to your tags so you might find someone who knows both (matlab was too many years ago for me).

Comment: You should read http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matlab, you can generate arrays with ":".
In python, you can create arrays using range() function or using arange (in numpy)

so,

```
 a = 3:5
```

in matlab is just the same as

```
a = np.arange(3,5) #or
a = np.array(range(3,5))
```

in Python.

Anyway, you might want to look at this page [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) in order to translate you code \ thought patterns from Matlab to Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean

```
data_1 = data[:,2:(2*Ntracks):2]
```

instead in your code, and similarly for `data_2`.

A few more things to note:

1. In `numpy` indices start from 0. `data[:,1:]` will skip the first column. Watch out for off-by-one error when doing the translation.
2. Slicing works slightly differently. The stride is specified by the last number, which is 2 in the above case, not the middle number (different from the `Matlab` convention).